# Finding sum of digits of $m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, permutations, combinations, self-learning, decimal-expansion

> If the sequence of 5 positive integers (a,b,c,d,e) satisfy:
>   $$abcde\leq {a+b+c+d+e} \leq 10m$$ then find the sum of digits of m.

I don't know how to approach this question. I know it's not a good way to ask here, but, if you may give any hint regarding this for the approach only, I will try my best to use it and apply.

Thank you. 
[image]

This is the question. And its answer is given as 9. I don't know how?

Comment: What is $m$? If it's just some number, the equation will be also valid for $m+1$.

Comment: There is no answer because there is no limit on $m$.  If $a=b=c=d=e=1$ we could have $m=1$, or $m=2$ or anything higher.  Please correct the question.

Comment: what is $abcde$? Is it five-digit number or a product?

Comment: @zenith:  No, $abcde$ has to be the product.  In your case the left side is at least $10000$ and will be larger than the middle.

Comment: What is m? It has no definition?

Comment: @Ross It is written in the same way as it is given in the assignment. If you want, I can post its picture.

Comment: Minimum $m=1$ when all are $1$. There is no max $m$, because $a=b=c=d=1$ and $e$ is free.

Comment: @jayant98-I think your question is find the sum of all minimum possible values of m i.e. for all combinations of a,b,c,d,e

Comment: @Ross You can see the source of question now.

Comment: I claim the problem is incorrect, and my answer is the best I can do to rescue it.  The point is that products tend to be greater than sums.

Comment: Is it from Rmo?

Comment: @tarit I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Presumably $m$ must be the minimum value that makes the right inequality true.  Unless some of $a,b,c,d,e$ are $1$, the product will be too large for the left inequality to hold.  Even if one of them is $1$, the product will be at least $16$ and that will be too large.  Work on justifying how small the sum must be.

If you are willing to count on the problem setter to have made sure there is a unique solution, you can just observe that $a=b=c=d=e=1$ allows $m=1$, assert that the sum of digits of $m$ must be $1$, and declare victory.  Really you should prove that any $a,b,c,d,e$ that satisfies the left must allow $m=1$

Note that $a=b=c=d=1$ allows $e$ to be anything, which means we can force the minimum $m$ to be as large as we want.  The problem is badly flawed.